# "description" vs. "reviewBody" for Review

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am wondering what is the right Schema.org use for a review in a product. I see two different suggestions:

Majory of sites I've checked use this structure:

```json
"review": {
  "@type": "Review",
  "author": "Daniela",
  "datePublished": "2016-11-01",
  "description": "Fantastic product! It really helped me. I would recommend to all my friends and family.",
  "name": "Awesome!",
 "reviewRating": {
  "@type": "Rating",
  "bestRating": "5",
  "ratingValue": "5",
  "worstRating": "1"
  }
 }
```

And it's correctly validated in structured data test tool.

However structured data helper and docs show this format:

```json
  "review" : {
    "@type" : "Review",
    "author" : {
      "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "Daniela"
    },
    "datePublished" : "2017-06-08",
    "reviewRating" : {
      "@type" : "Rating",
      "ratingValue" : "5",
      "bestRating" : "5",
      "worstRating" : "0"
    },
    "reviewBody" : "Fantastic product! It really helped me. I would recommend to all my friends and family. "
  }
```

They are similar, the only big difference is `description` vs. `reviewBody`.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different properties:

- [`description`](http://schema.org/description) gives a (typically short) description/summary/teaser of the review
- [`reviewBody`](http://schema.org/reviewBody) gives the full review

There is no reason to choose only one here. If you have the data for both, you can use both properties.

For Google’s Review rich result, simply [check the documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review):

- for a "Critic review", `description` is required
- for a "Review snippet", `reviewBody` is recommended

Comment: On the documentation page you've referenced it says Critic review is only for Local businesses, Movies, Books. And only Review snippet is connected to products. Did I get that right? (my question is not about Review, it's for Review in Product).

Comment: Also could you by the chance clarify "To participate, implement the markup, follow the guidelines for either critic review or review snippet, and register your interest in the pilot." Is it also related to product reviews?

Comment: @get9: Sorry, I’m not familiar with Google’s guidelines for these, and unless the question is about the markup to get these rich results, it’s off-topic here (would be on-topic on [webmasters.se]).